# Updating 4 SQL fields with PHP by user_id

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Is this possible to update 4 different columns based on a person "`user_id`" within the code?

I know there are a few examples but I'm having trouble understanding them, if someone could give me an example of how this would be done, so I can change my code accordingly I would be very grateful.

The code below works to update `field1`, but how can I tailor it to upload `field2`, `field3` and `field4` also?

```
<?php
include 'inc/db-connect2.php' ;
$dbname = "dtarg";

mysql_select_db($dbname);

$username = $_GET["username"];
$bianca = $_GET["bianca"];
$carla = $_GET["carla"];
$caroline = $_GET["caroline"];
$carrieanne = $_GET["carrieanne"];
$catherine = $_GET["catherine"];
$frazer = $_GET["frazer"];
$jason = $_GET["jason"];
$jay = $_GET["jay"];
$jordan = $_GET["jordan"];
$kim = $_GET["kim"];
$lindsay = $_GET["lindsay"];
$natasha = $_GET["natasha"];
$steph = $_GET["steph"];
$toby = $_GET["toby"];



$namequery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$username'"; 
$nameresult = mysql_query($namequery) or die(mysql_error());
while($namerow = mysql_fetch_array($nameresult)){
        $userid = $namerow['user_id'];
        $shift = $namerow['shift'];

}
$addrecord="UPDATE users
    SET field1 = CASE user_id
    WHEN '18' THEN '$bianca'
    WHEN '19' THEN '$carla'
    WHEN '20' THEN '$caroline'
    WHEN '7' THEN '$carrieanne'
    WHEN '16' THEN '$catherine'
    WHEN '21' THEN '$frazer'
    WHEN '15' THEN '$jason'
    WHEN '5' THEN '$jay'
    WHEN '11' THEN '$jordan'
    WHEN '10' THEN '$kim'
    WHEN '25' THEN '$lindsay'
    WHEN '6' THEN '$natasha'
    WHEN '1' THEN '$steph'
    WHEN '4' THEN '$toby'


    END
    WHERE user_id IN (18,19,20,7,16,21,15,5,11,10,25,6,1,4)";



    if (!mysql_query($addrecord))
        {
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }   

   ?>
```

EDIT 2 - This code seems to update field1, to the same value as field2?

```
    $addrecord="UPDATE users
    SET field1 = CASE user_id
    WHEN '18' THEN '$bianca'
    WHEN '19' THEN '$carla'
    END ,

    field2 = CASE user_id
    WHEN '18' THEN '$bianca'
    WHEN '19' THEN '$carla'
    END



    WHERE user_id IN (18,19,20,7,16,21,15,5,11,10,25,6,1,4)";



    if (!mysql_query($addrecord))
        {
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add a comma and reuse the logic :

```
SET field1 = CASE user_id
                   WHEN '18' THEN '$bianca'
                   WHEN '19' THEN '$carla'
                   .... END ,
    field2 = CASE user_id
                   WHEN '18' THEN '$bianca'
                   WHEN '19' THEN '$carla'
                   .... END ,
   ....
```

Comment: remove `SET` before `field2`

Comment: 'code'       
        $addrecord="UPDATE users
        SET field1 = CASE user_id
        WHEN '18' THEN '$bianca'
        WHEN '19' THEN '$carla'
        END ,


        SET field2 = CASE user_id
        WHEN '18' THEN '$bianca'
        WHEN '19' THEN '$carla'
        END

Seems to give me errors still, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Thankyou, this seems to remove the error, but sets field1 the same number as field2?

Comment: Please see Edit 2